# PHP BotMan Conversation implementation with widget

Tags: php, chatbot, botman

I am trying to implement the PHP BotMan with the botman widget,
however when I use reply it does send back the reply of the message. Now I am trying to do it with conversation and it is just giving me an JSON response back. Is there any way to send the reply message to the widget?

[This is](https://pastecode.xyz/view/423433db) the OnboardConversation.php File

Here is [chat.php](https://pastecode.xyz/view/8743b062)

Note that when I use from the chat.php

```
// Give the bot something to listen for.
$botman->hears('Hello', function (BotMan $bot) {
  $bot->reply('Hello too');
});
```

I do get the response in the chat widget but when I use the conversation I get the following.

> {"status":200,"messages":[{"type":"text","text":"Hello! What is your firstname?","attachment":null,"additionalParameters":[]}]}{"status":200,"messages":[{"type":"text","text":"Nice to meet you hello","attachment":null,"additionalParameters":[]},{"type":"text","text":"One more thing - what is your email?","attachment":null,"additionalParameters":[]}]}

I want this json response to be sent to widget, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you go straight to the fallback or do you get no reply at all?

Also you can try adding BotMan on the first line of the hears function.

```
$botman->hears('Hello', function(BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation);
});
```

You forgot the web driver manager as well

```
$config = [
    'web' => [
        'matchingData' => [
            'driver' => 'web',
        ],
    ]
];
```